# Is it possible to write a code without class methods, globals, and class variables?

Tags: java, python, ruby, language-design

I'm designing my own programming language for fun, and I'm thinking of making it fully Object-oriented (no statics, no globals, no class variables, no class methods), so I need to find a way to completely eliminate the needs of class methods, but, first, I need to make sure that I know all the problems that could only be solved by using class methods.

So, usually, class methods is used for creating helpers, and named constructors, yes? (Anything else?).

Currently, this is what I have to replace those with Object-oriented designs:

For example: the File helpers, I'm thinking of designing it like this:

```
class File
  def initialize(path)
    @path = path
  end

  def copy(destination)
    # Copy file from @path to destination
    # Then open destination path by creating new file instance
  end
end
```

*I'm actually using C, but I wrote the example in Ruby so it will be easier to understand.*

No class methods, and you could chain it like this:

```
File.new("directory/file").copy("new_path").copy("other_path")
```

If its too long, I could just drop the "new" method like what Python do:

```
File("directory/file").copy("new_path").copy("other_path")
```

Math helpers can be replaced with mixins:

```
module Math
  def pow(value)
    @value = @value ** value
  end
end

class Integer
  include Math

  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end
end
```

Call it like this:

```
Integer.new(100).pow(10).pow(10).pow(10)
```

In case you still need some helpers:

```
module Helpers
  # Some block of codes
end

class Object
  include Helpers
end
```

And now it's accessible everywhere.

To add more helpers, just modify the Helpers module:

```
module Helpers
  # Add more helpers
end
```

We can create factory class instead of named constructor:

```
class Lexer
  def initialize(source)
    @source = source
  end
end

class LexerFactory
  def create_from_file(file)
    return Lexer.new(File.read(file))
  end

  def create_from_string(string)
    return Lexer.new(string)
  end
end

class Base
  def initialize(lexer_factory)
    @lexer_factory = lexer_factory
  end

  def lexer
    @lexer_factory
  end
end

lexer = Base.new(LexerFactory.new).lexer.create_from_file("directory/file")
```

So my questions is: What am I missing? What you can't do without class methods, and class variables? What problems that could only be solved by using those?

Comment: This question looks similar to "why use an operator for addition if you can just use a function/method named `add`". I would say, go ahead and leave it out and see if you get into any real trouble or inconvenience. It is your language, so you can add them later on if you find you want them after all.

Comment: If you have a class with no variables or methods...what do your classes do?

Comment: I think he means static methods and variables.

Comment: `fully Object-oriented (no statics, no globals, no class variables, no class methods)` <-- This doesn't make any sense at all.. It's like saying "a car without wheels, doors, windows, or a gas peddle", that's a rock, not a car.

Comment: I thought in ruby it's called class methods... In PHP it's static methods. But there are instance variables and methods.

Comment: you said no statics though, so you're saying it will have static methods? This is not OO at all, far more functional approach, not bad necessarily but calling it OO is confusing and inaccurate

Comment: There are instance methods, and instance variables, but no static methods, and no static variables.

Comment: How would you implement singleton without statics?

Comment: IMHO singleton causes a lots of dilemma, yeah it can be helpful sometimes, but it took a lots of time to be sure when it's a good practise. Just create one object, then attach it to your main class or something, so everything must be dependency injected, it's a better practise, no? If the arguments gets too long, then i have to find a way to make it shorter, in more elegant way, like: Google's Guice. Yeah, it's a weird idea, no?, that's why i need to ask. And thanks for the answers.

Comment: @random_guy where does one "attach" it to the main class?  What structure holds the reference to the object in the *class*?

Comment: Design your language, on paper.  Use your language to solve real world problems, again on paper.  After you've actually used your language a couple of dozen times, go and develop your language.  Otherwise, you're reinventing PHP.

Comment: @MichaelT: You could have a local reference to a unique object in the main method, have all other unique objects depend on that, and inject any existing object (unique or not) in newly created objects as needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it possible to create a programming language or write object-oriented code without static/class methods/variables?  Absolutely.  Case study:  the Javascript programming language.  The key insight is that, if you squint a bit and hold your head at an awkward language, classes start looking like objects.  Special objects that do funny things when you poke them a certain way, sure, but objects nonetheless.  Add in a prototype system (as Javascript does), and suddenly you have not only the standard approaches for object-oriented code reuse, but many others too.  And all without special support for statics -- instead, just add a field to your "class" (which is actually an object) and you have a static/class variable.  Add a method to your "class" and you have a static/class method.

But what about globals?  Well, I'm not exactly sure what you mean by globals, so let's generalize and talk about [free variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables), or variables from some enclosing scope (including the global one, which is the "enclosing-est" scope there is :) ).  Can you imagine how hard it would be to write a program without free variables?  It's not fun :( , but people have tried and succeeded, and you might find [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_lifting) [articles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Y_combinator) interesting.

When you ask:

> So my questions is: What am I missing? What you can't do without class methods, and class variables? What problems that could only be solved by using those?

I think the real question you're getting at is "what are the minimal constructs needed to create a Turing-complete programming language?" or possibly "what are the minimal constructs needed to create a practical programming language?"

Those kinds of questions are awfully difficult to answer.  Like, PhD-worthy, which is why people spend their lives [researching answers to them](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/).  Perhaps learning about formal systems of computation, such as a lambda calculus, would help you to understand these questions better.  But ultimately, they're slippery slope questions, and nearly impossible to answer when you throw practical considerations (so that real people can use it) into the mix.  If you try hard enough, you can program without nearly every single modern programming construct -- does that mean it's all just sugar?

Comment: It *is* all just sugar, unless of course you're [flipping switches on the front panel](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/01/Altair_8800_Computer.jpg).  But sugar sure does help the medicine go down more smoothly.

Comment: "If you try hard enough, you can program without nearly every single modern programming construct". That answer my question. Thanks.